# Estimated cost for diy biohacking

Tags: biotechnology

How much would it cost (more precise the better) if i wish to start a diy bio lab in my own house. Assuming that all I want is a functional set and to create maybe simple things like glowing bacteria/glowing fish/deadly virus（jk)

Comment: are you talking about just combining premade store bought genes or or do you need to be able to discover new ones.

Comment: @John probably making my own? Since I dont think i know where i can acquire new genes

Comment: you can buy them in catalogues, I have actually done the glowing bacteria combination a dozen times with high school students.

Comment: Respectfully, I don't think this post is related to biology. This question could be answered 100% without ever mentioning a single biology concept. VTC.

Comment: @charles, true but it is a question I doubt anyone but a biological scientist could answer. However it might be better placed in world building.

Comment: @John Hmm.. I think that anyone who has access to eBay or Amazon could just search "DIY biohacking kit" and find a great deal of results, though they might not have an idea of what they're looking at.

Comment: @John You're not wrong, but I think that would place it better on a chat forum than on here.

Comment: *I don't understand the down votes;* this question has a clear answer that seems to show the question is reasonable. It may not be "fancy biology" but this appears to be a real thing.

Answer (score 2):

" ... you can get started for around $500 or less with a little improvisation and patience." -- [How to Set Up Your Own DIY Bio Lab](http://makezine.com/2017/04/11/how-to-set-up-your-own-lab/)

The $500 is pretty minimal and you won't get much done with that -- they mention other equipment (like a PCR machine) -- and you'd need to be *extremely* handy to be able to build all the equipment by hand.  More likely you're looking at thousands or several thousands of dollars.

Several sites give guidance:

- [A How-To For DIYbio Lab Equipment](http://diy-bio.com/diybio-lab-equipment/)
- [Genome at Home: Biohackers Build Their Own Labs](https://www.wired.com/2011/08/mf_diylab/)

Getting reagents may not be easy; I don't know how readily companies sell to individuals.

Don't forget that some experiments may require approval by animal care committees etc, unless you want to be arrested for animal abuse.

You might look into [biohacker collectives](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=biohacker+collectives&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8), which are shared spaces where multiple "hackers" can use common equipment.

Comment: I was certain these would all turn out to be joke links, but wow this is a thing! Are  PRC reagents for example controlled substances, or once you have a machine, can you just order them from Amazon? (err, I mean Aldrich)

Comment: PCR reagents aren't controlled (as far as I know) -- there's nothing toxic about them -- but the companies that carry them aren't used to dealing with individuals, so you might have a hard time ordering them.